# Basic Scala reflection code using recursive types does not compile. Why ? How can it be fixed?

Tags: scala, reflection, types, recursive-datastructures

The following Scala code, using the [recursive type](http://twitter.github.io/scala_school/advanced-types.html#fbounded) `A` does not compile:

```
package reflection.scala.stackOverflow

import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

class A[T<:A[T]]

class Question(root:A[_]) {
  val rtmMirror                   =runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
  val instanceMirror : InstanceMirror =rtmMirror.reflect(root)
}
```

It gives the following compilation error:

```
Error:(9, 50) type arguments [_$1] do not conform to class A's type parameter bounds [T <: reflection.scala.stackOverflow.A[T]]
  val instanceMirror : InstanceMirror =rtmMirror.reflect(root)
                                                 ^
Error:(9, 57) type arguments [_$1] do not conform to class A's type parameter bounds [T <: reflection.scala.stackOverflow.A[T]]
  val instanceMirror : InstanceMirror =rtmMirror.reflect(root)
                                                        ^
```

- Why does the compilation fail?
- What is the type argument $1 here ?
- Where does $1 come from ?
- Why does $1 not conform to A's type parameter bounds ?
- How can this code be modified so that it compiles while preserving compile time type checking of `root` to be a type of `A` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't tell it that the argument of `A` is of the right type, it will fill in an anonymous type parameter (the `_$1` is an anonymous type used for the argument of `A`) and won't necessarily make it as specific as it needs to be .  Just specify a valid type yourself instead:

```
class Question[T <: A[T]](root: A[T])
```

and the compiler will be happy.

Answer (score 1):

If you really don't care:

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime._
import scala.reflect.runtime._

scala> import universe._
import universe._

scala> class A[T<:A[T]] { def a: T = null.asInstanceOf[T] }
defined class A

scala> def f(x: A[_]) = currentMirror reflect[A[_]] x
f: (x: A[_])reflect.runtime.universe.InstanceMirror

scala> f(new A)
res0: reflect.runtime.universe.InstanceMirror = instance mirror for A@5b369cb9

scala> typeOf[A[_]].member(TermName("a")).asMethod
res1: reflect.runtime.universe.MethodSymbol = method a

scala> res0 reflectMethod res1
res2: reflect.runtime.universe.MethodMirror = method mirror for A.a: T (bound to A@5b369cb9)

scala> res2()
res3: Any = null
```

I want a black distressed tee that has on the front `X[_]` and on the back, `I dont care what type you think I am.`  Maybe more strongly worded.